plot only most abundant species in each facet of ggplot
I have a dataset which shows counts of each of a variety of species that occurred at different depths in different years, that looks like:
 df<-data.frame(species = rep(c("A","B","C","D","E"), each = 6),
 year = rep(c(2021,2022), each = 3, times = 5),
 depth = rep(c(10,20,30), times = 10),
 count = sample(1:10, 30, replace = TRUE),
 se = runif(30, 0.1,0.9))

There are actually around 50 species and 10 sites, but I simplified for my question. I would like to plot a bar graph with the top 3 most abundant species from each depth plotted in a separate facet. So far I have:
 ggplot(head(df,3), aes(x=reorder(species, - count), y=count, fill = year)) + 
 geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")+
 theme_bw()+
 xlab("Species")+
 ylab("Abundance (count +/- SE)")+
 geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=count-se, ymax=count+se), width=.2,
            position=position_dodge(.9))

But obviously this just plots the top 3 rows of the whole dataframe, not of each depth. Any help would be much appreciated!

I think you want slice_max from dplyr:
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

slice_max(df, order_by=count, n=3, by=depth) |>
  ggplot(aes(x=species, y=count, fill = factor(year))) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")+
  facet_grid(~depth, scales="free", labeller=label_both)+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(x="Species", y="Abundance (count +/- SE)", fill="Year")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=count-se, ymax=count+se), width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.9))


If you wanted to order by count within each facet, then replace aes(x=species) with what you had before (ggplot(aes(x=reorder(species, -count), ...)).
Edit 1:
My mistake. To order by count within each facet, you need to use reorder_within from the tidytext package as mentioned by @SamR.
slice_max(df, order_by=count, n=3, by=depth) |>
  ggplot(aes(x=reorder_within(species, -count, depth), y=count, fill = factor(year))) +
  scale_x_reordered() + ...


Edit 2:
OP would like exactly 3 species per facet. One way to do this is to aggregate the counts on species and depth (ignoring year) using summarise and then join this back to the original data frame.
semi_join(df, 
  summarise(df, count=sum(count, na.rm=TRUE), .by=c(species, depth)) |>
     slice_max(order_by=count, n=3, by=depth, with_ties=FALSE),
  by=c("species", "depth")) |>
  ggplot(aes(x=reorder_within(species, -count, depth), 
         y=count, fill = factor(year))) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")+
  facet_grid(~depth, scales="free", labeller=label_both)+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(x="Species", y="Abundance (count +/- SE)", fill="Year")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=count-se, ymax=count+se), width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.9))+
  scale_x_reordered()



set.seed(999) #df as in OP post.


Nice answer. On order, might be worth adding that reorder() applies the same order to each facet. To reorder each facet separately, I tend to use tidytext::reorder_within()

@SamR. Yes, that's a very good point. The OP didn't mention anything about ordering within the facets, although their code suggested that some ordering was possibly desired.

@Edward do you think there might be a way to get exactly 3 species in each facet? even if they are lower abundance in some years, maybe a way to specify the 3 most abundant in the whole dataset are shown in each year?
